# What is mistake in above sql?

Tags: mysql

I am unable to run this sql. This is not give me data.

```
$sql = "Select * from user where user_id=1'";

mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Do you have a valid connection?  Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: Looks like an extra ' at the end.  It is often useful to pull your query out and try it in some sort of tool.  Also what if any error are you getting?  More details would help us answer you better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

remove `'` after 1, this is silly mistake.

```
$sql = "Select * from user where user_id=1";

mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an unncessary ' after `1`. But also:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

mysql_query() - this extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Better solution: [MySQLi query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
$sql = "Select * from user where user_id=1";

mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove single quote (')

use this code:

$sql = "Select * from user where user_id=1";

mysql_query($sql);

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

$sql = "Select * from user where user_id=1";

mysql_query($sql);

single quote after 1 is unnecessary.(also, the Numeric Data Types is not placed inside quotes for example.. '1' or "1" is incorrect and will throw an error,just in case this is what you were trying to do.)